# Inclusion properties of interiors of subsets in a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I would like to verify my proof of the following exercise (Thanks in advance!):

> Let $A, B$ be two subsets of a topological space $X$. Prove that
>
> 1. If $A\subset B$, then $\text{Int }A \subset \text{Int } B$
> 2. $\text{Int }(A\cap B) = \text{Int }A \cap\text{Int }B$
> 3. $\text{Int }A \cup \text{Int }B \subset \text{Int }(A\cup B)$ but equality may fail.

**Proof**

1. Let $V$ an open set in $A$. Then $V$ open and imbedded in $B$, and $V\subset\text{Int }A, V\subset\text{Int }B$. But since $V$ was an arbitrary open set in $A$; $\text{Int }A \subset \text{Int }B$.
2. Let $V\subset\text{Int }(A\cap B)$. Then $V\subset A$ open and $V \subset B$ open ($V\subset A\cap B$ open). So that $V\subset \text{Int }A, V\subset \text{Int }B$ and $V\subset \text{Int }A\cap\text{Int }B$.
   Conversely, suppose $V\subset \text{Int }A \cap \text{Int }B$. Then $V\subset A$ open and $V\subset B$ open, which means $V\subset A\cap B$ open and $V\subset\text{Int }(A\cap B)$.
3. Suppose $x\in \text{Int }A \cup \text{Int }B$; and assume without loss of generality: $x\in \text{Int }A$. Choose $V$ open such that $x\in V\subset \text{Int }A$. This exists by definition of $\text{Int }A$.  Then $V\subset A$ open and $V\subset A\cup B$ so that $V\subset \text{Int }(A\cup B)$. But $x$ was arbitrary, so $\text{Int } A \cup \text{Int }B\subset \text{Int }(A\cup B)$.
   Conversely, suppose we take the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with $A=[0,1), B=[1,2)$. Then if we take $V=(\frac12, 1\frac12)$ we have $(\frac12, 1)\subset A$ and $(1, 1\frac12)\subset B$ which also lie in $\text{Int }(A\cup B) = \text{Int }[0,2)$. But $V\not\subset(\text{Int }A\cup \text{Int }B)$, for $1\not\in \text{Int }A \cup \text{Int }B.$

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the definition of $\operatorname{int}(A)$ as the largest open set contained in $A$ (i.e. $\operatorname{int}(A) = \bigcup \{O \in \mathcal{T}: O \subseteq A\}$. This implies that if we have any open set $O$ that is contained in $A$, we have $O \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A)$; I'll use this repeatedly under the shorthand "by maximality".

1. if $A \subseteq B$ then $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is open and as $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq A \subseteq B$, it is contained in $B$. It is thus one of the open subsets we use to form $\operatorname{int}(B)$, so $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(B)$, by maximality.
2. $\operatorname{int}(A) \cap \operatorname{int}(B)$ is open as a finite intersection of open sets and contained in $A \cap B$, as $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq A$ and ditto for $B$. Again by maximality: $\operatorname{int}(A) \cap \operatorname{int}(B) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A \cap B)$. On the other hand $\operatorname{int}(A \cap B) \subseteq A \cap B \subseteq A$ and the left hand side is open, so $\operatorname{int}(A \cap B) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A)$ by maximality again. A similar argument shows $\operatorname{int}(A \cap B) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(B)$ and combining these last two inclusions gives $\operatorname{int}(A \cap B) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A) \cap \operatorname{int}(B)$ and we have equality.
3. $\operatorname{int}(A) \cup \operatorname{int}(B)$ is open as a union of open sets and $\operatorname{int}(A) \cup \operatorname{int}(B) \subseteq A \cup B$, so maximality gives $\operatorname{int}(A) \cup \operatorname{int}(B) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A \cup B)$. In the reals (usual topology) we have that $\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$ (any non-empty open set contains an irrational, so is not contained in the rationals) and also $\operatorname{int}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$ (as every non-empty open set contains a rational). So taking these sets as $A$ and $B$ gives a rather extreme example that the reverse inclusion need not hold. Your example of $A = [1,2), B= [2,3)$ also works, of course.