# If $A$ is open and $A \subset B$, then $A \subset \operatorname{int}(B)$?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $A  \subset  \mathbb{R}^2$, $B  \subset  \mathbb{R}^2$, $A  \neq  \emptyset$,  $B \neq  \emptyset$. 
If $A$ is open and $A  \subset B$, then $A  \subset \operatorname{int}(B)$, is it true?

Comment: When you wrote that $A\in\Bbb R^2$ and $B\in\Bbb R^2$, perhaps that you meant that $A\subset\Bbb R^2$ and $B\subset\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: What is your definition of $int(A)$?

Comment: Check #1 in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2566598.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true. If you take any $x \in A$, since $A$ is open, there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset A$. But, since $A\subset B$, it is true that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset B$, which is exactly the definition of $x$ being in the interior of $B$.

Since we have shown that every $x \in A$ is also in the interior of $B$, we have shown that $A \subset \textrm{int} B$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since $\mathring{B}$ is the largest open set contained in $B$, and it is also the union of all open sets contained in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the interior of sets is compatible with set inclusion: $A \subset B \implies int(A) \subset int(B)$. For an open set $A$ it is true that $int(A) = A$.
(See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology))

These two imply the equality in your question:
$A = int(A) \subset int(B)$.

So the answer to your question is yes, it is true.